# Code signing issue: Developer Certificate expired, help?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, provisioning

The last time I deployed on a device was last week.  Since that time, I've been tweaking on the simulator.  My developer certificate expired on Oct 11th.  I tried to deploy on my iPhone today and got some code sign errors.  I checked it out and discovered my developer certificate expired, so I went ahead and renewed it on the Provisioning Portal.  Well, that didn't fix my problem, because now I see an error I've never had.  In the Organizer window, in the Provisioning Profiles pane, under the provisioning profile for my App bundle, I have a Yellow exclamation point:

```
"A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain."
```

I don't understand.  I have a renewed certificate and my private key is still here.  I feel like I'm going to go crazy.  Please help!  I can take screenshots but I don't know how to post them here.

Comment: See the accepted answer:  I had to delete my certificate, revoke it in the provisioning portal on the developer site, and then reapply for a certificate by following the instructions.  I also had to create a new provisioning profile after creating the new certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I had something similar after installing a new hard drive and rebuilding the machine. I'd suggest blowing away all the certs and stuff and start again with requesting a cert and installing into the keychain. The get a new provision profile etc. I.e. Pretend this is the first time.

It's easy through the portal and only takes a few minutes. That worked for me.

Comment: ++ I wish I tried that a long time ago.  I've been Googling for 100 years on this.  I revoked my certificate, deleted it from Keychain.app, and then reapplied.  I had to create a brand new provisioning profile.  Now it works again.